# C++ program to add two integers

Tags: c++

These below are the two ways to add two integers using user defined function but both are different because one uses int type function and the other one uses void type function but in the both case I am getting the same output So I am literally confused which one to choose. So please tell me the difference between these and which one to choose. Thanks in advance

Using int type funtion(user defined function):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int add(int, int);
int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 6, sum;
    sum = add(a, b);
    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
int add(int x, int y)
{
    int add;
    add = x + y;
    return add;
}
```

using void type(user defined function):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void add(int, int);
int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 6;
    add(a, b);
    return 0;
}
void add(int x, int y)
{
    int add;
    add = x + y;
    cout << add;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it more readable.

Comment: The first is much better because the second should be called "addAndPrint". The second function is much less useful than the first.

Comment: It depends, if you want the value of addition in the caller, return it (int version in your case). If you are not interested in the value of addition and just want to display use the void version.

Comment: Like cristid9 said, the two examples are fundamentally different.  Consequently, your question makes no sense.  For an apples-to-apples comparison, you'd need to remove the "cout" from the second example from "add()" to "main()".  Q: What happens when you try?  Q: Why?  *That's* what's important for you to understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print the sum of two integers you can use a `void` function. If you need the sum for further computing, you return the sum.

Answer (score 5):

The 2 functions are fundamentally different. The first one returns the sum (which is later printed in `main`) and the second one doesn't return anything, it just prints the sum. Which one to use depends on you. Generally, people want modular code, so the one returning the sum might be of more use.

Comment: Okay!...but which one is superior?

Comment: And you choose what to use based on your needs. There is no "better that the other" in this situation.

Comment: @BikrantKoirala See my cooment now, I've updated it.

Comment: @BikrantKoirala _"which one is superior?"_ In which particular regards? Reusability, performance, memory consumption?

Comment: @BikrantKoirala The one using `cout` might take more time.

Comment: Since `std::cout` will likely take 100s of clock cycles and the addition will take only a few the std::cout version will be significantly slower.